# Want to Open a new Tab by appending parameter in the querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, tabs

I want to open a new tab when thru the parameter in the query string.

For an example,I have four tabs (t1, t2,t2,t4). Right now, i have implemented the code that whenever user puts http://abc.net/disc_apps.jsp**#tab3**, it automatically opens tab3.For that i have written a function in document.ready, so for that I need to refresh the page or have to open a new tab and then have to enter a new query string.

But, now i am trying to implement http://abc.net/disc_apps.jsp**?defaultTab=tab3** functionality, where i don't have to open a new tab every time or don't have to refresh the page.

please help me as I am new to these things.

thanks in advance.
Hemish

Comment: The concrete problem/question is very hard to understand because the terminology used is not expliciet and too high-level and therefore your question is very ambiguous and even confusing. Please clarify more. For example, what exactly do you mean with tabs? UI tabs in your page? Browser tabs? Also, what exactly do you mean with "have to open a new tab" and "have to refresh the page"? Why do you need to do that? A properly written $(document).ready() should take that into account already. Anyway, some code would help a lot in understanding your problem better. See also http://sscce.org

Comment: @Baluc: Thanks for the rply.I have 4 UI tabs, clicking on which, new content is loaded on the page with AJAX calls.I have written a code to make ajax calls if you put http://abc.net/disc_apps.jsp#tab3 directly into URL.So, i grab the content tab3 from thr URL and trigger the click event with that.But for that, everytime i have to refresh a page and then only I the change in the URL takes effect.For an ex- if I have tab2 and need to change it to tab3 then i have to refresh a page first.

Comment: Now, I want to change this to http://abc.net/disc_apps.jsp?defaultTab=tab3,and I dont want to refresh page everytime. so is there anyway for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deciphering the question and reading the comments up to three times, your **concrete problem** turns out to be the following:

> *I want to change the hash fragment in the URL when I change a tab in the UI.*

Using query strings isn't the solution. They are server side and not controllable from the client side on without firing a HTTP request (or, "refreshing the page" as you call it yourself). Hash fragments are however controllable from the client side on. It's extraordinary easy as well: just use it as-is in tab links.

```
<a href="#tab1">tab1</a>
<a href="#tab2">tab2</a>
<a href="#tab3">tab3</a>
```

The webbrowser will change the hash fragment in the browser address bar by itself. I however assume that you already have a jQuery function which already shows the desired tab content when any of those links is clicked (and doesn't return false from the function!).

Comment: Thanks Baluc, It has helped. SOrry for the ambiguous language. :)